# Is there a way in gherkin-cucumber to compare a json file with item box?

Tags: javascript, testing, cucumber, testcafe, gherkin

Cucumber does't accept loop. 
So I'm looking for a way to do a comparison from json file with an item box.
I been trying dataTables as shown below.

```
Given I have 3 country names
    |  no  |  countryName  |
    |  1   |  Afganistan   |
    |  2   |  Albania      |
    |  3   |  Algeria      |
```

I want to compare, or those who made match with this table list and a list box

Comment: I don't believe you need json for this. Have you tried reading the data table item and then check if it's exist in the list? Share your step def. We can give you more insight with other options.

Comment: What do you mean with "Cucumber doesn't accept loop"? Could you clarify what you are trying to do?